# Spring boot - partial update best practise?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data

I am using Spring boot v2 with mongo database.  I was wondering what is the best way to do partial updates on the data model.  Say I have a model with x attributes, depending on the request I may only want to update 1, 2, or x of them attributes. Should I be exposing an endpoint for each type of update operation, or is it possible to expose one endpoint and do it in a generic way? Note I will need to be able to validate the contents of the request attributes (e.g tel. no. must be numbers only)

Thanks,

Comment: Did you find out what is the best practice?

Comment: This seems to be a very trivial requirement, but couldn't find any viable solution still.  https://www.baeldung.com/spring-rest-json-patch uses json patch for this and it works. Only downside is that the request needs to be `application/json-patch+json` which is not very REST-friendly for a PATCH in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

HTTP PATCH is a nice way to update a resource by specifying only the properties that have changed.
The following [blog](https://www.infoworld.com/article/3206264/application-development/how-to-perform-partial-updates-to-rest-web-api-resources.html) explain it very well

Comment: Thanks, but in the blog example, the CustomerPatchRequest is specific to just the city and the country.  If i wanted to do firstName and lastname, this would mean a different request object and a different endpoint, which I want to avoid

Answer (score 0):

You can actually expose just one endpoint. This is the situation I had a few months ago:

I wanted people to modify any (or even all)fields of a Projects document (who am I to force the users to manually supply all fields lol). So I have my Model,
Project.java:

```
package com.foxxmg.jarvisbackend.models;
//imports

@Document(collection = "Projects")
public class Project {
    @Id
    public String id;
    public String projectTitle;
    public String projectOverview;
    public Date startDate;
    public Date endDate;
    public List<String> assignedTo;
    public String progress;

   //constructors

    //getters & setters
}
```

I have my repository:

ProjectRepository.java

```
 package com.foxxmg.jarvisbackend.repositories;
//imports

    @Repository
    public interface ProjectRepository extends MongoRepository<Project, String>, QuerydslPredicateExecutor<Project> {
//please note, we are going to use findById(string) method for updating
        Project findByid(String id);
//other abstract methods 


    }
```

Now to my Controller, ProjectController.java:

```
package com.foxxmg.jarvisbackend.controllers;
        //import

        @RestController
        @RequestMapping("/projects")
        @CrossOrigin("*")
        public class ProjectController {
            @Autowired
            private ProjectRepository projectRepository;

    @PutMapping("update/{id}")
        public ResponseEntity<Project> update(@PathVariable("id") String id, @RequestBody Project project) {
            Optional<Project> optionalProject = projectRepository.findById(id);
            if (optionalProject.isPresent()) {
                Project p = optionalProject.get();
                if (project.getProjectTitle() != null)
                    p.setProjectTitle(project.getProjectTitle());
                if (project.getProjectOverview() != null)
                    p.setProjectOverview(project.getProjectOverview());
                if (project.getStartDate() != null)
                    p.setStartDate(project.getStartDate());
                if (project.getEndDate() != null)
                    p.setEndDate(project.getEndDate());
                if (project.getAssignedTo() != null)
                    p.setAssignedTo(project.getAssignedTo());
                return new ResponseEntity<>(projectRepository.save(p), HttpStatus.OK);
            } else
                return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        }
     }
```

That will allow partial update in MongoDB with Spring Boot.

Comment: While this works, I don't think this is a good practice because what if there are about 50 fields? Should we `if` check all these 50 fields?

Comment: good approach, only drawback is to make field null. if i want to make field to null then it will keep old value.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Mapstruct then this blog is very helpful
https://cassiomolin.com/2019/06/10/using-http-patch-in-spring/

the idea is simple,

- You load the entity from DB
- You convert that entity to dto same type as the payload sent in the API request
- Then you apply merge/patch operation on the payload & the converted dto from last step [utlity included]
- The output is merged dto
- You convert that merged dto to the entity
- You save the entity

example from the blog:

```
@PatchMapping(path = "/{id}", consumes = "application/json-patch+json")
public ResponseEntity<Void> updateContact(@PathVariable Long id,
                                          @RequestBody JsonPatch patchDocument) {

    // Find the domain model that will be patched
    Contact contact = contactService.findContact(id).orElseThrow(ResourceNotFoundException::new);
    
    // Map the domain model to an API resource model
    ContactResourceInput contactResource = contactMapper.asContactResourceInput(contact);
    
    // Apply the patch to the API resource model
    ContactResourceInput contactResourcePatched = patch(patchDocument, contactResource, ContactResourceInput.class);

     // Update the domain model with the details from the API resource model
    contactMapper.update(contactResourcePatched, contact);
    
    // Persist the changes
    contactService.updateContact(contact);

    // Return 204 to indicate the request has succeeded
    return ResponseEntity.noContent().build();
}
```

P.S Using mapstruct you will have an easy control on properties mapping, map something to something else or even ignore, this is beneficial if you have a `customerId` long type and you want to map it to `customer`

Answer (score -3):

If you are using Spring Data MongoDB, you have two options either use the [MongoDB Repository](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/2.1.2.RELEASE/reference/html/#mongo.repositories) or using the [MongoTemplate](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/2.1.2.RELEASE/reference/html/#mongo-template.save-update-remove).

Comment: How does this help exactly?  This is the model update but I was asking about how to expose the end points and request object(s)

Comment: You could just use one endpoint with `PUT` and pass in the model for the persistent service which uses the above strategies.